# Proving $DF = EF$ without trigonometry

Tags: euclidean-geometry, triangles

> In the isoscales $\triangle ABC$ ($AB=AC$), if $BE = CD$, prove $DF=EF$.
>
> [image]

I used Sine Rule for triangles $\triangle BEF$ and $\triangle CDF$ and concluded that $DF = EF$. I'm wondering can you solve this problem without trigonometry?

Comment: Consider the reflection with respect to the altitude of the isosceles triangle. Let $D'$ and $E'$ be the images of those. The lines $DD'$, $BC$ and $EE'$ will be parallels. Use Thales's theorem (intercept theorem).

Comment: @NDB please, comment is not meant for a short answer or even some hint. Either write an answer or ask for clarifications.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

Take point $K$ on $AB$ such that $BK=BE$.

Since $\triangle ABC$ is an isosceles,

then $KD \parallel BC \parallel BF$

and

$EF = FD$ (line through midpoint $\parallel$ to the second side)

Answer (score 2):

Drop perpendicular $EG$ to the extended side $BC$ and perpendicular $DH$ on $BC$. Then by $ASA$ congruence we have $\triangle EBG\cong\triangle DCH$ and $EG=DH$. But then by $ASA$ again $\triangle FGE\cong\triangle FHD$ and $EF=DF$.